# Dependency of Image::Imlib2 on CpanTesters

Tags: perl, cpan

I get a lot of errors on CpanTesters for my module [EBook::MOBI::Image](https://metacpan.org/module/EBook%3a%3aMOBI%3a%3aImage)
(It is just some additional stuff for [EBook::MOBI](https://metacpan.org/module/EBook%3a%3aMOBI). Like this I keep graphics-dependencies from the main module away for those who don't need it anyways).
All tests, except those for GNU/Linux fail:

http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/E/EBook-MOBI-Image.html#EBook-MOBI-Image-0.11

Since I only have GNU/Linux and have some lack of experience in general, I ask for some help here.
The test results seem to indicate, that there is a problem with the dependency of [Image::Imlib2](https://metacpan.org/module/Image%3a%3aImlib2)

http://www.cpantesters.org/cpan/report/2306795e-99db-11e2-8c80-50d7c5c10595

There it says I should take care, that Image::Imlib2 is in the "Makefile.PL", but it is there as you can see:

https://metacpan.org/source/BORISD/EBook-MOBI-Image-0.11/Makefile.PL#L24

Image::Imlib2 itself does not have this issues. Tests pass all the systems:

http://www.cpantesters.org/distro/I/Image-Imlib2.html#Image-Imlib2-2.03

Can somebody give a hint here what is wrong?
The code is hosted here:

https://github.com/borisdaeppen/EBook-MOBI-Image

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I try to install this module (on Cygwin) with the `cpan` command:

1. cpan recognizes that I need the `Image::Imlib2` module (`warning: prerequisite Image::Imlib2 0 not found`)
2. cpan downloads and attempt to build `Image::Imlib2`
3. build of `Image::Imlib2` fails (`you must install the imlib2 library before you can install Image::Imlib2 ... Make has some problems, won't install`)
4. cpan continues to build `EBook::MOBI::Image` (`... Continuing, but chances to succeed are limited`)
5. and of course, the tests for `Ebook::MOBI::Image` fail

The `PREREQ_PM => ...` directive in `Makefile.PL` tell cpan to make an effort to satisfy a prerequisite, but as you see, it will continue the build even if the prerequisite fails to install. The `PREREQ_PM` directive is good enough for most modules on CPAN, but not for modules that need an external library that cpan can't install on its own.

I think what you want in this case is for the cpan tester to bail out if you can't load the `Image::Imlib2` module, and the place to do that is early in `Makefile.PL`.

```
if (!eval "require Image::Imlib2") {
    print "This distribution requires Image::Imlib2!\n";
    exit 0;
}
```

For systems that can't or won't install `Image::Imlib2`, bailing out of `Makefile.PL` will cause the tester to report a result of `N/A` instead of `FAIL`.

Comment: Thx a lot, I'll check this asap (first dinner :-) ) But I first need to find out how to influence a Makefile.PL with a dzil-build-process.

Comment: I used Dist::Zilla::Plugin::Run to modify Makefile.PL after the building by adding this to my dist.ini in the "[Run::AfterBuild]" part: "run = sed -i '5iif (!eval "require Image::Imlib2"){print " -- This distribution requires Image::Imlib2! -- ";exit 0;}' %d/Makefile.PL"